# The best way to search a site using PHP/MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I'm in need of implementing a solid site search solution to our framework.
It has to search all pages and data.

I could make my own using MySQL, though after reading some blogs I realize there are a lot of things to take into consideration. Plus; I rather not re-invent the wheel.

About a year ago, I've worked with Zend_Search_Lucene. Loved the way of building indexes and then searching them later when needed. Though I found Zend_Search_Lucene sometimes gave inacurate results, so I don't really trust it anymore.

**Requirements**

- backend solution only (I want to output results myself)
- results have to be (as good as) live (max a few hours delay)
- results have to be complete
- results have to be sorted by relevance
- should not require any installation on server (I use clustered hosting on which I can't install anything)
- no advertisements

Do you know of a solution that is solid, trustworthy and meets these demands?

**UPDATE 1***

This searching solution will not need to handle a high amount of traffic for now. It is acceptable that when a solution is required to handle high amounts of traffic and data, we'll get another server on which we can install a good solution.

Comment: no installation? that eliminates all the good candidates.

Comment: How is your data structured? That's where it starts or do you want to use a crawler running through your website?

Comment: Yes, that's a major drawback. Would've loved solr. 
Most data sits in a MySQL database. I'd rather not use a crawler to index data. I would love to just update a search index when data changes or every so often.

Comment: I once used a MySQL to do the job http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html . I created a separate table for my case. Don't know any specifics about your case but hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. I will probably do just that. Create a custom search index table in MySQL and just put searchable content in there. Seems the best way to go for now.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I used to use a simple implementation of a search system. Many moons ago this was the best way to go for a 'no server installation' method.

```
http://www.sphider.eu/
```

Let us know how you get on. You do need a database, but presumably you have a clustered database which you could offload the data onto. If your solution isn't MySQL based, then this would require a lot of work, but for simple and straight forward crawling and searching it's definitely the way forward.

There is also a very easy to run cron-job script built in (if memory serves me well).

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion. I have tried sphider out a loong time ago as well. I was about to give it a secnod chance untill I saw the last release date: 2009. I think I will probably go for a custom solution on MySQL.

Comment: If you end up making a decent one let us know, I think there's a hole in the market for this exact solution!